# How to prevent a block of code from being interrupted by KeyboardInterrupt in Python?

Tags: python

Hitting <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> while the `dump` operation is saving data, the interrupt results in the file being corrupted (i.e. only partially written, so it cannot be `load`ed again.

Is there a way to make `dump`, or in general any block of code, uninterruptable?

---

My current workaround looks something like this:

```py
try:
    file = open(path, 'w')
    dump(obj, file)
    file.close()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    file.close()
    file.open(path,'w')
    dump(obj, file)
    file.close()
    raise
```

It seems silly to restart the operation if it is interrupted, so how can the interrupt be deferred?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Put the function in a thread, and wait for the thread to finish.

Python threads cannot be interrupted except with a special C api.

```
import time
from threading import Thread

def noInterrupt():
    for i in xrange(4):
        print i
        time.sleep(1)

a = Thread(target=noInterrupt)
a.start()
a.join()
print "done"


0
1
2
3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\test.py", line 11, in <module>
    a.join()
  File "C:\Python26\lib\threading.py", line 634, in join
    self.__block.wait()
  File "C:\Python26\lib\threading.py", line 237, in wait
    waiter.acquire()
KeyboardInterrupt
```

See how the interrupt was deferred until the thread finished?

Here it is adapted to your use:

```
import time
from threading import Thread

def noInterrupt(path, obj):
    try:
        file = open(path, 'w')
        dump(obj, file)
    finally:
        file.close()

a = Thread(target=noInterrupt, args=(path,obj))
a.start()
a.join()
```

Comment: This solution is better than the ones involving the `signal` module because it's much easier to get it right. I'm not sure that it's even possible to write a robust `signal`-based solution.

Comment: Ok, so it seems that the thread won't continue to print after you break the thread in python 3 - the interrupt appears immediately, but the thread is still carrying on in the background

Comment: What if you wanted to return something from the noInterrupt() function? Will 'a' the variable get the return value?

Comment: Don’t use that code, it does not work on Linux or MacOS as it relies on a Windows-only issue: currently on Windows, `threading.Lock.acquire` (and therefore other synchronization primitives such as  `threading.Thread.join`) cannot be interrupted with Ctrl-C (cf. https://bugs.python.org/issue29971).

Comment: ^ I confirm this does not work on Linux

Answer (score 91):

The following is a context manager that attaches a signal handler for `SIGINT`. If the context manager's signal handler is called, the signal is delayed by only passing the signal to the original handler when the context manager exits.

```
import signal
import logging

class DelayedKeyboardInterrupt:

    def __enter__(self):
        self.signal_received = False
        self.old_handler = signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, self.handler)
                
    def handler(self, sig, frame):
        self.signal_received = (sig, frame)
        logging.debug('SIGINT received. Delaying KeyboardInterrupt.')
    
    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, self.old_handler)
        if self.signal_received:
            self.old_handler(*self.signal_received)

with DelayedKeyboardInterrupt():
    # stuff here will not be interrupted by SIGINT
    critical_code()
```

Comment: Even though it may look daunting to some at first, I think this is the cleanest and most reusable solution.

After all, you're defining the context manager only once (and you can easily do that in its own module, if you like) and then you only need one ''with'' line wherever you want to use it, which is a big plus for the readability of your code.

Comment: Thanks for this.  For anyone testing this solution, don't just try it with a single time.sleep call in place of critical_code.  It will exit right away. (Maybe that's typical of other solutions -- I'm not sure)

Comment: @Justin: that is because signal handlers can only occur between the “atomic” instructions of the Python interpreter. (3rd point from https://docs.python.org/library/signal.html)

Comment: @Perkins: But that will shadow `something` from the global namespace. If this is an issue for you because you have a global called `signal`, then the best solution is to put this code in it's own module.

Comment: Only if `something` is used elsewhere.  Mechanically, it works fine, just like shadowing `list` works fine, it just makes for slightly less readable code.  In case it wasn't clear before, I'm talking about the local variable `signal` in `DelayedKeyboardInterrupt.handler`, not the `signal` module.  Typical shorthand for `signal` would be `sig`, which doesn't shadow anything.

Comment: Great class, thank you. I extended it to support multiple signals at once - sometimes you also want to react to `SIGTERM` in addition to `SIGINT`: https://gist.github.com/tcwalther/ae058c64d5d9078a9f333913718bba95

Comment: **This code is buggy; do not use it.** Possibly nonexhaustive list of bugs: 1. if an exception is raised after `signal` is called but before `__enter__` returns, the signal will be permanently blocked; 2. this code may call third-party exception handlers in threads other than the main thread, which CPython never does; 3. if `signal` returns a non-callable value, `__exit__` will crash. @ThomasWalther's version partly fixes bug 3 but adds at least one new bug. There are many similar classes on Gist; all have at least bug 1. I advise against trying to fix them—it's way too hard to get this right.

Comment: @benrg Wow, that's a pretty defeatist attitude. The bugs that you describe would only be encounter in very obscure situations that can easily be avoided. Just because this might not be suitable for all situations, dose not mean it is not suitable for none.  I really think your comment is nonconstructive.

Answer (score 38):

Use the [signal](http://docs.python.org/library/signal.html) module to disable SIGINT for the duration of the process:

```
s = signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_IGN)
do_important_stuff()
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, s)
```

Comment: I would have gone for that too if it was in a unix like system

Comment: This does work on windows. It happens via emulation of the Posix signals via the C runtime library https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdkz3x12%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: Much easier and simpler than threads, great solution. Thanks.

Comment: If a signal occurs during the execution of `do_important_stuff()`, does the signal fire once it is un-ignored?

Comment: I think this is the cleanest solution most of the time. Only problem is when you don't work in the main thread: "signal only works in main thread". Hmpf.

Answer (score 11):

In my opinion using threads for this is an overkill. You can make sure the file is being saved correctly by simply doing it in a loop until a successful write was done:

```
def saveToFile(obj, filename):
    file = open(filename, 'w')
    cPickle.dump(obj, file)
    file.close()
    return True

done = False
while not done:
    try:
        done = saveToFile(obj, 'file')
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print 'retry'
        continue
```

Comment: +1: This approach is much more pythonic and easier to understand than the other two.

Comment: +- 0: This approach isn't as good because you can interrupt it forever by holding down crtl+c while my thread approach never gets interrupted. Also note that you have to have another variable "isinterrupted" and another condition statement to reraise it afterwards.

Comment: This approach also restarts the dump every time, which is part of what I wanted to avoid.

Comment: @Unknown, @Saffsd: You are both right. But this solution is intended for simple applications, where you don't expect malicious use. It is a workaround for a very unlikely event of a user interrupting the dump unknowingly. You can choose the solution that suits your application best.

Comment: No, @Saffsd is not right. He should just move dump() out of saveToFile(). Then call dump() once and saveToFile() as many times as it's needed.

Comment: Actually disabling signals seems for me the most natural way. In this case we do not suppress them, we just repeat the action till our signal is not suppressed (if we are lucky that is). It's almost exactly like in base author of question has written. This a reason why I am down voting this answer.

Comment: I'm concerned about repeating things in the context of the generic code. Let's say we do an API request with access limits or call some hardware device with the intention that the operation shouldn't repeat. Looping simply isn't universal.

Answer (score 5):

I've been thinking a lot about the criticisms of the answers to this question, and I believe I have implemented a better solution, which is used like so:

```py
with signal_fence(signal.SIGINT):
  file = open(path, 'w')
  dump(obj, file)
  file.close()
```

The `signal_fence` context manager is below, followed by an explanation of its improvements on the previous answers. The docstring of this function documents its interface and guarantees.

```py
import os
import signal
from contextlib import contextmanager
from types import FrameType
from typing import Callable, Iterator, Optional, Tuple
from typing_extensions import assert_never


@contextmanager
def signal_fence(
    signum: signal.Signals,
    *,
    on_deferred_signal: Callable[[int, Optional[FrameType]], None] = None,
) -> Iterator[None]:
    """
    A `signal_fence` creates an uninterruptible "fence" around a block of code. The
    fence defers a specific signal received inside of the fence until the fence is
    destroyed, at which point the original signal handler is called with the deferred
    signal. Multiple deferred signals will result in a single call to the original
    handler. An optional callback `on_deferred_signal` may be specified which will be
    called each time a signal is handled while the fence is active, and can be used
    to print a message or record the signal.

    A `signal_fence` guarantees the following with regards to exception-safety:

    1. If an exception occurs prior to creating the fence (installing a custom signal
    handler), the exception will bubble up as normal. The code inside of the fence will
    not run.
    2. If an exception occurs after creating the fence, including in the fenced code,
    the original signal handler will always be restored before the exception bubbles up.
    3. If an exception occurs while the fence is calling the original signal handler on
    destruction, the original handler may not be called, but the original handler will
    be restored. The exception will bubble up and can be detected by calling code.
    4. If an exception occurs while the fence is restoring the original signal handler
    (exceedingly rare), the original signal handler will be restored regardless.
    5. No guarantees about the fence's behavior are made if exceptions occur while
    exceptions are being handled.

    A `signal_fence` can only be used on the main thread, or else a `ValueError` will
    raise when entering the fence.
    """
    handled: Optional[Tuple[int, Optional[FrameType]]] = None

    def handler(signum: int, frame: Optional[FrameType]) -> None:
        nonlocal handled
        if handled is None:
            handled = (signum, frame)
        if on_deferred_signal is not None:
            try:
                on_deferred_signal(signum, frame)
            except:
                pass

    # https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#signal.getsignal
    original_handler = signal.getsignal(signum)
    if original_handler is None:
        raise TypeError(
            "signal_fence cannot be used with signal handlers that were not installed"
            " from Python"
        )
    if isinstance(original_handler, int) and not isinstance(
        original_handler, signal.Handlers
    ):
        raise NotImplementedError(
            "Your Python interpreter's signal module is using raw integers to"
            " represent SIG_IGN and SIG_DFL, which shouldn't be possible!"
        )

    # N.B. to best guarantee the original handler is restored, the @contextmanager
    #      decorator is used rather than a class with __enter__/__exit__ methods so
    #      that the installation of the new handler can be done inside of a try block,
    #      whereas per [PEP 343](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) the
    #      __enter__ call is not guaranteed to have a corresponding __exit__ call if an
    #      exception interleaves
    try:
        try:
            signal.signal(signum, handler)
            yield
        finally:
            if handled is not None:
                if isinstance(original_handler, signal.Handlers):
                    if original_handler is signal.Handlers.SIG_IGN:
                        pass
                    elif original_handler is signal.Handlers.SIG_DFL:
                        signal.signal(signum, signal.SIG_DFL)
                        os.kill(os.getpid(), signum)
                    else:
                        assert_never(original_handler)
                elif callable(original_handler):
                    original_handler(*handled)
                else:
                    assert_never(original_handler)
            signal.signal(signum, original_handler)
    except:
        signal.signal(signum, original_handler)
        raise
```

**First, why not use a thread (accepted answer)?**

Running code in a non-daemon thread does guarantee that the thread will be joined on interpreter shutdown, but any exception on the main thread (e.g. `KeyboardInterrupt`) will not prevent the main thread from continuing to execute.
Consider what would happen if the thread method is using some data that the main thread mutates in a `finally` block after the `KeyboardInterrupt`.

**Second, to address [@benrg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5670773/benrg)'s feedback on the most upvoted answer using a context manager:**

> 1. if an exception is raised after signal is called but before `__enter__` returns, the signal will be permanently blocked;

My solution avoids this bug by using a generator context manager with the aid of the `@contextmanager` decorator. See the full comment in the code above for more details.

> 2. this code may call third-party exception handlers in threads other than the main thread, which CPython never does;

I don't think this bug is real. `signal.signal` is required to be called from the main thread, and raises `ValueError` otherwise. These context managers can only run on the main thread, and thus will only call third-party exception handlers from the main thread.

> 3. if signal returns a non-callable value, `__exit__` will crash

My solution handles all possible values of the signal handler and calls them appropriately. Additionally I use [`assert_never`](https://hakibenita.com/python-mypy-exhaustive-checking) to benefit from exhaustiveness checking in static analyzers.

---

Do note that `signal_fence` is designed to handle **one** interruption on the main thread such as a `KeyboardInterrupt`. If your user is spamming <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> while the signal handler is being restored, not much can save you. This is unlikely given the relatively few opcodes that need to execute to restore the handler, but it's possible. (For maximum robustness, this solution would need to be [rewritten in C](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/90882#issuecomment-1190313695))

Comment: doesn't work on windows /other platforms, thread version does tho

Comment: It seems to work on Windows 10 / Python 3.10 that I tested just now. signal_fence(signal.SIGINT) correctly deferred the KeyboardInterrupt from my command prompt. There are some other comments on this answer that suggest Python emulates these Unix signals on Windows from CTRL_C_EVENT/CTRL_BREAK_EVENT

Answer (score 4):

This question is about blocking the `KeyboardInterrupt`, but for this situation I find atomic file writing to be cleaner and provide additional protection.

With atomic writes either the entire file gets written correctly, or nothing does. Stackoverflow has a [variety of solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333872/atomic-writing-to-file-with-python), but personally I like just using [atomicwrites](https://pypi.org/project/atomicwrites/) library.

After running `pip install atomicwrites`, just use it like this:

```
from atomicwrites import atomic_write

with atomic_write(path, overwrite=True) as file:
    dump(obj, file)
```

Answer (score 1):

A generic approach would be to use a context manager that accepts a set of signal to suspend:

```
import signal

from contextlib import contextmanager


@contextmanager
def suspended_signals(*signals):
    """
    Suspends signal handling execution
    """
    signal.pthread_sigmask(signal.SIG_BLOCK, set(signals))
    try:
        yield None
    finally:
        signal.pthread_sigmask(signal.SIG_UNBLOCK, set(signals))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not interruptible (try it), but also maintains a nice interface, so your functions can work the way you expect.

```
import concurrent.futures
import time

def do_task(func):
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1) as run:
        fut = run.submit(func)
        return fut.result()


def task():
    print("danger will robinson")
    time.sleep(5)
    print("all ok")

do_task(task)
```

and here's an easy way to create an uninterruptible sleep with no signal handling needed:

```
def uninterruptible_sleep(secs):
    fut = concurrent.futures.Future()
    with contextlib.suppress(concurrent.futures.TimeoutError):
        fut.result(secs)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my attempt at a context manager that can defer signal handling, based on the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/71330357/1319998

```py
import signal
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def defer_signal(signum):
    # Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/71330357/1319998

    original_handler = None
    defer_handle_args = None

    def defer_handle(*args):
        nonlocal defer_handle_args
        defer_handle_args = args

    # Do nothing if
    # - we don't have a registered handler in Python to defer
    # - or the handler is not callable, so either SIG_DFL where the system
    #   takes some default action, or SIG_IGN to ignore the signal
    # - or we're not in the main thread that doesn't get signals anyway
    original_handler = signal.getsignal(signum)
    if (
            original_handler is None
            or not callable(original_handler)
            or threading.current_thread() is not threading.main_thread()
    ):
        yield
        return

    try:
        signal.signal(signum, defer_handle)
        yield
    finally:
        signal.signal(signum, original_handler)
        if defer_handle_args is not None:
            original_handler(*defer_handle_args)
```

that can be used as:

```
with defer_signal(signal.SIGINT):
   # code to not get interrupted by SIGINT
```

The main differences:

- Doesn't attempt to defer handlers that are not Python handlers, e.g. it allows the system default if it's set, or for the signal to be ignored
- Restores the original single handler before calling it due to a signal that happened during the deferral
- It's a "last signal wins" rather than "first signal” wins. Not really sure if that's a meaningful difference, but it's a touch simpler.

But there are still cases where it might never restore the original handler... say there is another handler for another signal that raises an exception just after `finally:`. It just might be impossible in pure Python because of the fact exceptions can just "get raised" anywhere by signal handlers.

But - if you're not adding such handlers, and just concerned about SIGINT/KeyboardInterrupt, then I suspect it's robust(?)