# store some data in the struct inode

Tags: linux, filesystems, linux-kernel, kernel, inode

Hello I am a newbie to kernel programming.  I am writing a small kernel module
that is based on wrapfs template to implement a backup mechanism. This is
purely for learning basis.

I am extending wrapfs so that when a write call is made wrapfs transparently
makes a copy of that file in a separate directory and then write is performed
on the file. But I don't want that I create a copy for every write call.

A naive approach could be I check for existence of file in that directory. But
I think for each call checking this could be a severe penalty.

I could also check for first write call and then store a value for that
specific file using private_data attribute. But that would not be stored on
disk. So I would need to check that again.

I was also thinking of making use of modification time. I could save a
modification time. If the older modification time is before that time then only
a copy is created otherwise I won't do anything. I tried to use inode.i_mtime
for this but it was the modified time even before write was called, also
applications can modify that time.

So I was thinking of storing some value in inode on disk that indicates its
backup has been created or not. Is that possible? Any other suggestions or
approaches are welcome.

Comment: Formatting your blob goes a long way to getting your question even _read_.

Answer (score 0):

You are essentially saying you want to do a Copy-On-Write virtual filesystem layer.

IMO, some of these have been done, and it would be easier to implement these in userland (using libfuse and the fuse module, e.g.). That way, you can be king of your castle and add your metadata in any which way you feel is appriate:

- just add (hidden) metadata files to each directory
- use extended POSIX attributes (setfattr and friends)
- heck, you could even use a sqlite database

If you really insist on doing these things in-kernel, you'll have a lot more work since accessing the metadata from kernel mode is goind to take a lot more effort (you'd most likely want to emulate your own database using memory mapped files so as to minimize the amount of 'userland (style)' work required and to make it *relatively easy* to get atomicity and reliability right<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup>
On [How Everybody Gets File IO Wrong: see also here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433057/is-rename-without-fsync-safe/7433149#7433149)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I would take a look at using fuse. But actually I have started out with using wrapfs. I have changed unlink code to call rename instead of unlink so If something I could do like manipulating any struct inode attribute to suit my needs

Answer (score 0):

You can use `atime` instead of `mtime`. In that case setting `S_NOATIME` flag on the inode prevents it from updating (see `touch_atime()` function at the `inode.c`). The only thing you'll need is to mount your filesystem with `noatime` option.

Comment: @liya :Why couldn't I use mtime ? But the problem with using atime is that it will be modified if file is read so that would be a problem with this approach.

Comment: @gaurav: With `noatime` mount option there is no `atime` update on access.

Comment: Ohh I see Good option I see, But I don't see why atime works and mtime doesn't. Also would atime of lower FS also won't change ?