# Transaction-based archive container

Tags: transactions, filesystems, archive

I'm creating a Windows service that runs when a specific USB key is plugged in.
What it does is simple: contact an FTP server, download some files, and store
them in an (encrypted) archive on the USB. The archive can be opened read-only
with a tool provided to the client (but that's irrelevant to my problem).

The service is used to keep the USB in sync with the master server (pretty much like Dropbox, but only download and the synchronized folders are on the removable media). The archive can grow up to a few gigabytes. About 1GB of the files are updated every week on the keys of around 400 users.

Since the entire update process is transparent to the user, there is the non-negligible chance that they *unplug* the USB when data is being written to the archive (even if I put some kind of screaming, flashy warning: **DO NOT UNPLUG**). Corrupting the archive would require to download it again in its entirety, that means quite a lot of bandwidth wasted on the already loaded servers.

So basically I need the writes to the archive to be *transacted*. It's OK if they fail, as long as they do not put the container in an inconsistent state. Either the file is entirely written, either it is *not*. It's OK if the file is partially written if the container does not actually "see" it.

**The question is here:**
How can I guarantee data consistency at all times? Specifically, how do you make IO operations to work as transactions? What would you suggest? Shall I implement something on my own? Or are there already containers that offer this functionnality?

This is what I've got so far:

- **Create a new archive, rename on commit**: not possible, the archive is too large.
- **Zip / Tar / 7z**: unsuitable, a failed write will corrupt the archive
- **Truecrypt**: unsuitable, as it requires a file system driver (Administrator privileges that the users dot *not* have).
- **Anything that requires mapping a file system to a file**: unsuitable, pretty sure you can't do that without being Administrator, but if it's possible, it'd be great.
- **Storing files in a SQLite DB**: it's ACID so that could indeed be a solution. However, it would require splitting the files as SQLite has a limited BLOB capacity. Not very elegant, but I'm ready to go that way. Also SQLite's transaction journal can get pretty large when storing large blobs.
- **Implement that on my own**: I'd rather avoid that as much as possible but I'm not afraid to do it. I just find the topic pretty complex.

If this question is too general please move it to SU or something.

Comment: Is the USB formatted as NTFS?

Comment: @Fanael Yes, else the archive wouldn't fit anyway.

Comment: In this case, and if you're interested only in Vista and above, maybe you should try `CreateFileTransacted` and its friends?

Comment: To be honest, an 'inplace modifiable archive' of that size has a name: it's called **a filesystem**. I suggest you use one. Btrfs, Nilfs, Logfs, Zfs are pretty decent when comes to being atomic and consistent. Xfs/ext4 have good track records (Xfs with large files, in particular)

Comment: @Fanael The `Transacted*` NTFS calls are only for creating/moving/etc. Not modifying data.

Comment: Oh really? I recall `CreateFileTransacted` + `WriteFile` + `CloseHandle` working just fine, but my memory may be betraying me.

Comment: @Fanael the guarantees cover the metadata, not the object data. Also 'working just fine' means nothing in the realm of _resilience/reliability_

Comment: @sehe: unless I misunderstood, MSDN disagrees. It says that the file streams *are* fully transactional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try using something like svn or git to download encrypted differences; they typically can be used to reconstruct a file locally if it gets corrupted.  Or just download diffs and use patch to generate the latest file version.

You have other problems if the user unplugs a FLASH drive while it's in the process of writing data.  Many are not reliable (at the flash block level, not the file system level) and can be corrupted to the point that a journaling file system like NTFS or EXT3 cannot recover. There's more detail here: https://superuser.com/questions/290060/can-flash-memory-be-physically-damaged-if-power-is-interrupted-while-writing

Comment: I do not control the remote servers. However your last paragraph is very interesting and made me think a while. Maybe I'm just going to not transact anything at all.

Comment: You can run git locally; you can use its versioning capabilities to rebuild a file that gets corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

it's pretty simple, really. write to temporary, then set as master if the write finishes, else delete and try again.

Comment: As I said that's not possible, the archive is way too large.

Comment: Don't make it sound too simple: **[Is rename() without fsync() safe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433057/is-rename-without-fsync-safe)**

Answer (score 0):

Maybe our [SolFS](http://www.eldos.com/solfs/) (Application Edition) will work. SolFS offers a virtual file system within a container file, and it supports journalling mode of data writing, which helps keeping the filesystem integral.