# hard link created suddenly on NAND flash

Tags: bash, embedded-linux, hardlink

I was surprised by a hard link created suddenly between a config file that I (as usr1) own and a temporary file that I create in an OS daemon (each 5 minutes), to copy from the original config file.

After copying back to the original file, I use rename(*file2, *file1); in C which kills any trace to config.txt.tmp

The directory is root owned on a mnt /sram drive, and no one has a root access over the embedded machine.
The storage media is NAND flash SRAM on embedded Linux 2.6.10

`ls -l` shows

```
2 config.txt       699byte date_modify  
2 config.txt.tmp   699byte date_modify
```

config.txt.tmp should get created, copied from config.txt, send config parameters to config.txt then gets deleted atomically within 5-7 C lines only

The directory is root owned, and there is no way to create hard links.

Anyone has an explanation of "hard link" creation in the low level functions?
Could I be facing a race condition? Or could it be some kernel code for storage over flash? Or a bug in Linux?

My code ran over 5 years, 100 machines, and ONLY 1 machine recently got this problem.

Comment: It isn't clear from your various prose descriptions what operations are being done on what files. Could you make it, like, _exceedingly_ clear? Use _exact filenames_, identify processes involved in each action, list the steps _in sequence_, POSIX funtion names instead of 'send config parameters to config.txt' (you ***cannot*** send text to a file, perhaps to a socket), and what does 'atomic deletion' mean, especially seeing that it takes multiple lines?

Comment: I amended my answer with more info

Answer (score 1):

Check whether the files are *actually* hardlinks by doing

```
ls -i
```

to show inodes.

Of the top of my head:

- file buffers may have been dirty before move?
- if a fork is involved, again, dirty buffers may be at play even from before the fork
- is a flash 'overlay' filesystem driver present? Perhaps it has changed and contains an optimization that it previously didn't

  Think

  - unionfs
  - aufs
  - ...?

**Edit**

> FWIW: From your text, I get the impression you might be doing things in reverse: I'd expect you to write to a .tmp copy, and once everything is flushed & synched, 'atomically' (well, cross fingers for filesystem support and ordering mode) rename it into place. (I'm just guessing now, because most of the picture is too hazy to actually go on)

Also see: [Is rename() without fsync() safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433057/is-rename-without-fsync-safe/7433149#7433149)

Comment: sehe
sorry for the late response, yes I see the same number referencing those two files after ls -i.
I am thinking like this - only less than 50 units are suffering that out of 100s of thousands - I dont believe it is about the file system itself.
I am expecting the app from a certain programmer opens those files and does some certain function call sequence.
But the trouble is NOONE gives his code.
Any ideas?
thanks

Comment: perhaps strace/ptrace can shed some light on what other programs are doing - if you can't get the source. OllyDbg/WinDbg on windows