# Opening a file in a Python module and closing it when the script ends

Tags: python, file

I have a Python module that performs some logging during some of the methods it contains:

**module.py**

```
LOG_FILE = "/var/log/module.log"

def log(message):
    with os.fdopen(os.open(LOG_FILE, os.O_RDWR | os.O_CREAT, 0664), "a+") as f:
        f.write("[%s] %s\n" % (time.strftime("%c"), message))

def do_something():
    log("Doing something")
    # ...
```

In this implementation the log file will be opened and closed every time the `log` method is called.

I'm considering refactoring it so the file is opened once when the module is loaded, but I'm not sure how to ensure it is closed when a script importing the module ends. Is there a clean way to do this?

**Edit:** I'm not asking about closing the file when an exception is encountered, but when the script that imports my module exits.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do files get closed during an exception exit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17577137/do-files-get-closed-during-an-exception-exit)

Comment: you don't have guarantees. However, if you are looking for a "best effort" behaviour, check `atexit`

Comment: Why not use `apache http server`,`mod_wsgi`,`logger` and let them handle the writes to log files. Faster, efficient.. or just use a `logging` [module](https://docs.python.org/2.3/lib/node304.html)

Comment: @Vaulstein Because it's not running as a CGI script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OS takes care of open file descriptors then a process dies. It may lead to a data loss if file buffers inside the application are not flushed. You could add `f.flush()` in the `log()` function after each write (note: it does not guarantee that the data is physically written to disk and therefore it is still may be lost on a power failure, see [Threadsafe and fault-tolerant file writes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12003805/4279)).

Python may also close (and flush) the file on exit during a garbage collection. But you shouldn't rely on it.

`atexit` works only during a normal exit (and exit on some signals). It won't help if the script is killed abruptly.

As [@René Fleschenberg suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31073766/4279), use `logging` module that calls `.flush()` and perhaps registers `atexit` handlers for you.

Answer (score 1):

Python is usually pretty good at cleaning up after itself.  If you must do something when the script ends, you need to look at the [`atexit` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/atexit.html) - but even then, it offers no guarantees.

You may also want to consider logging to either `stdout` or `stderr`, depending on purpose, which avoids keeping a file around all together:

```
import sys

def log(message):
    sys.stderr.write("[%s] %s\n" % (time.strftime("%c"), message))
```

Comment: I already do log to `stderr`, this is just some extra logging. `atexit` looks promising, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Python will automatically close the opened files for you when the script that has imported your module exits.

But really, just use Python's [logging module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html).

Comment: So there's no need to explicitly close any files? I'll have a look at `logging` but at the moment it's quicker and easier to do it manually rather than messing around setting up paths, permissions, and formats.

Comment: Whether files are automatically closed at the end depends on the Python implementation, as far as I know. It is not a good practice to rely on it.

Comment: It's good practice to explicitly close files, but if you only want to close on program exit, you can let Python do that for you.

Comment: I recommend looking at the logging module *now*. It may seem like your current method is quicker and easier, but it is actually harder and more complicated, which is why you are asking this question ;)