# Is basic_managed_mapped_file.flush() immediately written to disk？

Tags: boost

I use `basic_managed_mapped_file` and I want to backup the file while the program is running.

How can I make sure the data is written to disk for the backup?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is logically "yes".

The operating system will make sure that the data is written, I believe even if your process would crash next.

However, if you

- must be sure that the data hit the disk before doing anything else
- need to ensure that data hits the disk in any particular order (e.g. journaling/intent logging)
- need to be sure that data is safely written in the face of e.g. power failure

then you will need to add a disk `sync` call on most OS-es. If you require this level of detail (and worse, in portable fashion), the topic quickly becomes **hard**, and I defer to

> **[eat my data: how everybody gets file IO wrong](http://www.linux.org.au/conf/2007/talk/278.html)** from [Stewart Smith](https://www.flamingspork.com/blog/2007/11/27/libeatmydata/)

I've also mirrored the video/slides just in case (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7433149/85371))