# In-place editing a file

Tags: linux, file, posix, edit

I am writing a program to change a file in place. The semantics I want are that the old version should remain on the file system until the new version has been written. That is, the transition between from the old to the new version should happen atomically. What is the right way to do this on Linux or, preferably, any POSIX system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The canonical way to do it atomicaly is to create a temporary file, and when you're done, you move it to overwrite the original file. Then you enter a whole other domain of problems. Have a look at this [Is rename() without fsync() safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433057/is-rename-without-fsync-safe)

Answer (score 0):

Write the new file under a different name, then call `rename`.

Answer (score 0):

> I am writing a program to change a file in place

The already existing program is `patch`.

Run `diff -[option] old-file new-file >> name.patch`

e.g. `diff -Naur old-file new-file >> name.patch`

... and use the patch command to edit the file, like `patch -p0 < name.patch`