# Pythonic API that enables efficient file creation with known content

Tags: python, api, file-io, io

The question is about API design. The scenario is, I have some bytes of KNOWN length in memory and I want to design a Pythonic API that flushes them to `AWS S3` with few `RPCs`. By Pythonic, I mean if there is already an accepted API doing this, I want to copy it.

One way is to do something like `io.create(filename, content)`. This can be translated into a single `HTTP` request using `S3` `XML` API.

The traditional `open`, `write`, and `close` pattern is a streaming API. `open` doesn't accept a length argument so the created stream doesn't know it should buffer all writes into a single RPC.

Of course the API can look like:

```
with open(filename, buffering="UNLIMITED") as f:
   f.write(content)
```

But buffering doesn't really support `"UNLIMITED"` constant.

So what can I do? File a PEP? Thanks.

Comment: why do you think you need atomic creation? are you running into resource collisions? or just trying to stay ahead of a curve that you imagine must be out there? (IE are you actually being impacted by not having atomic file creation?)

Comment: possible duplicate of [atomic writing to file with Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333872/atomic-writing-to-file-with-python)

Comment: I don't believe atomic creation would work in this case, since the purpose is to limit RPC on NFS shares.

I looked into this some time ago, as I was writing metadata files onto Isilon NFS shares.  I never came up with a good solution, so I ended up using io.BytesIO and io.StringIO and then writing out the file object.

Answer (score 0):

NFS, at least in version 2 and 3, isn't terribly good at doing locking or atomicity.

The best bet, again at least in NFS 2 and 3, is to create your file with a temporary name, and then use os.rename().

Perhaps some progress has been made on this in NFS 4; I don't know.