# Calling python script from TCL and creating a file atomically

Tags: python, file, tcl, atomic

I wrote a python script that takes care of creating a file atomically as described in this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333872/atomic-writing-to-file-with-python).  The file that gets created by the script is somewhat big (about ~1.5MB) as seen below:

```
$ ./my_script.py --output_file some_directory/my_file.txt
$ ls -l --block-size=K some_directory/my_file.txt
-rw------- 1 foouser foogroup 1477K Aug  7 17:39 some_directory/my_file.txt
```

Unfortunately, due to some legacy infrastructure and the way things are set up, this script needs to be called from within a TCL script.  Here is the way in which I am currently doing that:

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh
set PY_SCRIPT my_script.py
puts [exec $PY_SCRIPT --output some_directory/my_file.txt]
```

The problem that I am seeing is that the generated file does not seem to be created atomically anymore (atomicity is a requirement for my application).  The [TCL puts command documentation](https://wiki.tcl.tk/919) says the following:

> Tcl buffers output internally, so characters written with puts may not
>   appear immediately on the output file or device; Tcl will normally
>   delay output until the buffer is full or the channel is closed.

I believe this explains why my file is not being atomically created anymore.  I'm not an expert in TCL, so I am not sure how to accomplish atomic file creation in the TCL script.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why is there any need for `puts`?  You're still using my_script.py to produce all the output you need, right?  Shouldn't you just exec that script in tcl?

Comment: You are aware that files that size are not normally written atomically? The usual size of a true atomic write is around 16 kB, though the OS might provide a view that simulates atomicity. Everything is more noticeable on Windows, due to the impact of anti-virus software (which often spoils the atomicity properties of writes).

Comment: @DonalFellows Based on their linked question, OP seems to be misusing the concept of atomic writes to simply mean "either all or none of the file is written".

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is just [`flush stdout`](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/flush.htm).

Answer (score 0):

A direct translation of the Python code that you link to would be something like this (untested code):

```
package require Tclx

set f [open $tmpFile w]
puts -nonewline $f $text
sync $f    ; # flush is performed implicitly
close $f

file rename -force $tmpFile $myFile
```

The TclX package is needed to get the `sync` command. (This will probably not work on Windows.)

Comment: Wouldn't a `flush $f` be sufficient here (no TclX dependency), to clear the buffer; `rename` will serve for the `all-writes-or-none` requirement?

Comment: @mrcalvin: not sure anymore: I've mostly left Tcl behind now, and I can't figure this out just by looking at the code. Sorry.