# Updating a JSON file's key value

Tags: python, json

I have a json file

```
{
    "id_1" : "",
    "id_2": ""
}
```

I'm trying to update the value for each using the following function

```
    async def UpdateID(self):
        await self.bot.wait_until_ready()
        while not self.bot.is_closed():
            id1 = 1
            id2 = 2
            with open("file.json", "r+") as r:
                config_json = json.load(r)
                config_json.update({"id_1": "%s" %(id1)})
                config_json.update({"id_2": "%s" %(id2)})
                json.dump(config_json,r)
            await asyncio.sleep(120)
```

Using mode `r+`, it copies the file and adds it to the end, thus duplicate all the data instead of replacing. If I use `r`, I can't write.

If I use `w` or `a`, I get an `UnsupportedOperation`, `not readable` error on the `json.load` step. Using `w` also makes the file empty.

`a+ and w+,` give a `JSONDecodeError`,`Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)` error on the `json.load` step.

Am I using the wrong mode, or an improper way of fixing the original problem?

Comment: I just tried using `r+` and adding `r.seek(0)` before the dump and `r.truncate()` after. Is that a proper way to go about it?

Comment: Yes, that's the solution.

Comment: Why use `config_json.update` instead of simply `config_json["id_1"] = str(id1)`?

Comment: Bit of a failsafe I guess in case for whatever reason the key doesn't exist, `update` will create it, right?

Comment: So does assigning to the dictionary element.

Comment: I think you're confusing it with lists, where you can't create an element with assignment.

Comment: Since you figured out the solution yourself, you can post your own answer.

Comment: Well, "proper" is stretching it -- `seek(0)` + write + truncate is more prone to leaving your file corrupt or half-written if your program exits abruptly, the system is rebooted at the wrong time, etc. Best practice is to create a new temporary file, write all your content to _that_, and then rename the temporary file over the original when it's fully flushed to disk. See [atomic write to file using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333872/atomic-writing-to-file-with-python).

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
import json

async def updateId(self):
    do_something()

    with open(file_name) as f:
        config = json.load(f)

    update_your_config()

    with open(file_name, 'w') as f:
         json.dumps(config, f)

    do_something()
```