# Abort python script after a special function finished running

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python script, that has a long runtime. 
Sometimes I need to abort it and run it later. It dumps the current results in a pickle file, but while aborting (CTLR + C) at the wrong time that file gets corrupted.

Is there a way to let the script finish that task and abort it afterwards?
I don't know where to look for.

Thank you

Edit: My program looks somewhat like this:

```
import pickle


for key in keylist:
    do_smth(mydict)
    with open('myfile.p','w+b') as f:
       pickle.dump(mydict,f)
```

Edit2: Thank you guys, try: ... except: ... works like a charm.
Since I am the only user of the script I won't need the "save" version. However I will definitely look into it (right now I am not familiar with threading).

I also changed my loop, that I will only pickle my file, in case of an exception or after the loop finished.

```
import pickle

for key in keylist:
    try:
        do_smth(mydict)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
         print("Saving data ...")
         with open('myfile.p','w+b') as f:
             pickle.dump(mydict,f)

     with open('myfile.p','w+b') as f:
         pickle.dump(mydict,f)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> actually throws a special type of exception called `KeyboardInterrupt`. So, if your way of aborting the script to run it later is sending that exception, you can save your data before exiting. This can be done by wrapping your code in a `try-except` block and catch the `KeyboardInterrupt` exception.
An example would look like this:

```
try:
    # your main code here
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    # do the saving here
    exit(-1)   # exit the program with the return code -1
```

About the comment: make sure that you send this exception once.
It's because if you send it, the code will go to the saving part, that does not have the exception-catching block. So if you send it multiple times, your data may be saved improperly.

Comment: however, the saving might be interrupted by CTRL+C, again

Comment: @DomTomCat No, it can't. The exception is generated by the user, who is interested in keeping his data. So I doubt that he will send it multiple times. Of course, it's a possibility, but then it would be simpler to just advice the user. The simpler, the better

Comment: well it still can and will - at the latest when someone else uses the code! but yes, they'll probably be careful, right. But also the data can get corrupt, too - e.g. it's just being updated when CTRL+C is invoked

Answer (score 3):

You want to protect two operations:

1. the update of your data (not necessarily the computation)
2. the writing of your data, once CTRL+C has been hit

With a `try`, `except` block only, both of these can simply be interrupted and leave your data or outputfile in a corrupted state.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/842567/1150303) has an interesting comment:

> Python threads cannot be interrupted except with a special C api.

So what you may want to do is to catch `KeyboardInterrupt` in your code and within this `except` branch, start a thread which writes out the current data. I've made an example:

```
import time
from threading import Thread

def heavy(n):
    for i in range(10000):
        time.sleep(1)
        print("doing some computation")

def noInterrupt(path, obj):
    try:
        print("interrupted, writing out data (try to press CTRL+C again)...")
        for i in range(5):
            time.sleep(1)
            print("...wrote block %d/5" % i)
    finally:
        print("DONE writing file")


mydata = []
try:
    # press CTRL+C somewhere here
    # manipulate data
    for i in range(1000):
        heavy(i)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    a = Thread(target=noInterrupt, args=("path/to/file", mydata))
    a.start()
    a.join()
```

NOTE: Don't forget, the manipulation of your data can get corrupted with `KeyboardInterrupt`, too, so you might want to make sure you protect the process of updating your data (with another thread?)

Comment: By the way, `print(heavy(i))` will output both `"doing some computation"` and `"None"`, since you're printing the return value of the function `heavy`

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a handler for `KeyboardInterrupt`:

```
import signal
import sys
def signal_handler(signal, frame):
        #make sure you save the file
        sys.exit(0)
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
```