# How to disable interruption with Ctrl+C in cmd/python

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd

I have a program that has quite a few functions, each running on a separate thread.
When the user presses `Ctrl+C`, only 1 thread crashes with an exception, but because of this, the whole program may not work correctly.

Of course, I can write this construction in each function:

```
try:
    do_something()
except KeyboardInterrupt as e:
    pass
```

but, as I said, there are many functions, perhaps there is an option not to prescribe this construction in each function?

Or is it possible to disable `Ctrl+C` interrupt in cmd settings?
For example, in the *registry*. The program creates its own registry key in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\MyProgrammKey`

**UPD 1**

```
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_IGN)
```

It helped in almost all cases except one: a thread that has an infinite loop with the `input()` function anyway interrupts.

**UPD 2**

Here is a sample code

```
import signal, time
from threading import Thread


def one():
    while True:
        inp = input("INPUT: ")


def two():
    while True:
        print("I just printing...")
        time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_IGN)
    Thread(target=one).start()
    Thread(target=two).start()
```

**UPD 3**

Screenshot of exception.
[image]

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/842557/18238422) might help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Ctrl+C` will send `SIGINT` signal to program, so you could define a global signal handler to ignore that `SIGINT`, something like next:

**test.py:**

```
import signal, os, time

def handler(signum, frame):
    pass

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handler)

time.sleep(10)

print("done")
```

During the program run, if you input `Ctrl+c`, the program will ignore it, and continue to run, finally print `done`:

```
$ python3 test.py
^Cdone
```

Comment: [`SIG_IGN` might be better](https://stackoverflow.com/a/842807/18238422)

Comment: @Pychopath Sure, if we no need do anything in handler.

Comment: @atline, thanks, it helped in almost all cases except one: a thread that has an infinite loop with the input() function anyway interrupts.

Comment: @Mus1k Would you show the minimal code?

Comment: @atline, updated.

Comment: @Msu1k Er... what's the running result on your side, it still works perfectly on my side using the same code your affords... How you judge it not work?

Comment: @atline, updated again.

Comment: @Mus1k YES, the difference is you use windows, while I'm using linux. It looks ok on linux. So what I suggest is wrap try...except around input, if you are using windows. You can't find a proper way to `except KeyBoardInterrupt` because there so many functions, but I think it's easy to `except EOFError` as you are sure to know where you use `input()`...