# Julia - Is there a way to prevent a block of code from being immediately interrupted by Ctrl+C/SIGINT in Julia?

Tags: julia

There is this answer for python from an old thread which I used in the past to great effect (see first answer here [How to prevent a block of code from being interrupted by KeyboardInterrupt in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842557/how-to-prevent-a-block-of-code-from-being-interrupted-by-keyboardinterrupt-in-py)). I'd like to know if it is possible to do something similar in Julia.

That's pretty much it, but here's some background.

I'm developing a Markov Chain Monte Carlo algorithm in Julia and I need to insure that the state of the chain is always valid, especially following a Ctrl+C/SIGINT. This is particularly important during development in the REPL where I want to be able to stop the chain but then restart it where it was left off without having to start from scratch and wait for the burn-in period all over again.

As it stand it is almost always the case that the chain will be in an invalid state following a SIGINT.

In other words I want to have blocks of code that are uninterruptibles, namely critical blocks within which a SIGINT is deferred until the block has terminated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[disable_sigint](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/c/#Base.disable_sigint) prevents a block of code to be interrupted immediately, whereas catching `InterruptException` is a mean to handle the interrupt:

```
try
    disable_sigint() do
        for i in 1:5
            sleep(1)
            print(".")
        end
    end

    println("\nnow it is safe to interrupt immediately")
    while true
        sleep(1)
        print("*")
    end
catch InterruptException
    println("interrupt catched")
end
```

If running a script remember [how to catch Ctrl-C](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/faq/#catch-ctrl-c):

```
julia -e 'include(pop!(ARGS))' script.jl
```

`disable_sigint` is able to mask the `InterruptException` generated by a `SIGINT` signal (for example a signal coming from a
[kill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kill) command on unix). For example if the running code is notified throwing directly an `interruptException()` it is interrupted as soon as possible ignoring the `disable_sigint` directive.

This may be the case of a jupyter environment where communication between client and kernel processes happens through a IPC channel (ZeroMQ transport channel) or the case of vscode where a "supervisor" process manage a child julia execution context.

Chances are that the kernel interrupt command delivered from jupiter frontend to jupyter kernel backend that "supervises" julia code is not delivered to child process using a SIGINT OS-signal.

Comment: This is almost exactly what I need. The only remaining issue is that there is almost no code, or very fast code, outside of the do block, so the window of time during which `SIGINT` can be caught is micro/milliseconds, much too short for human reflexes. This is because `disable_sigint()` truly disables and throws away `SIGINT` rather than queues/delays/defers it until exiting the do-block. Here it only works because of the artificial `sleep(1)` line.

Comment: Are you sure? On my side I've tried on windows and linux and the SIGINT is queued and handled correctly at the termination of disable_sigint block without code
outside do block (just wrapping disable_sigint with a while true).

Comment: I'm on MacOS. I can confirm that it actually works but only when using the REPL directly. When using the REPL within VSCode it interrupts immediately even within the do-block. When using IJulia in jupyter it simply throws the SIGINT away and doesn't interrupt wrapping the do-block within a while-true.

Comment: Thanks for the details, I've added some general considerations about the jupyter/vscode cases, I hope they may help.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense! I noticed in Jupyter+IJulia using an enclosing while true loop (no slow block) that while it doesn't interrupt after a single interrupt signal, if you insist and send repeated interrupt signals it will eventually interrupt the code with a warning message `WARNING: Force throwing a SIGINT`. I don't understand how this work.

But regarding VSCode you're saying that it throws an InterruptException() directly without SIGINT, thus bypassing the effect of disable_sigint() and interrupting immediately?

Comment: I said "it may be ..." because it sounds reasonable but I do not know exactly the internals of jupyter and vscode plugin.
Looking at [vscode sources](https://github.com/julia-vscode/julia-vscode/blob/master/scripts/packages/VSCodeServer/src/eval.jl#L60) reveals that an InterrupException() is delivered directly.

Comment: You were right about VScode https://github.com/julia-vscode/julia-vscode/issues/2936

Answer (score 3):

Ctrl+C/SIGINT causes the `InterruptException`, so you can place your code within a `try` block and catch the `InterruptException`.

```
  try
    # ... your algorithm here ...
  catch e
    if e isa InterruptException 
      save_your_chain_to_a_valid_state()
      then_exit()
    else
      rethrow()
    end
  end
```

If you're running the code outside of the REPL, you'll first have to call `Base.exit_on_sigint(false)` before the `try` block.

Comment: The problem with this approach I think is that it's the code within the ```try``` block that needs to finish completely because it is within it that there's a small window of time where the state is invalid. If it is interrupted I cannot easily repair and restore it into a valid state by calling a second function, here ```save_your_chain_to_a_valid_state()```

Comment: You can think of it as a single line of code that does some critical heavy lifting, i.e. popping and pushing some things around within the state during a Gibbs update. If at anytime this line is interrupted the state becomes invalid and it's a pain to repair. I really need to defer the throwing of the ```InterruptException```.